# Setting up DotBot & Antigen

Tags: git, zsh, zshrc, dotfiles

**I am setting up some dotfile configurations. I am using [DotBot](https://github.com/anishathalye/dotbot) for automating `symlinks`**

Here is my a list of my files on my `.dotfile` folder

```
.git            antigen         install         zshrch
.gitmodules     dotbot          install.conf.yaml
```

**This is the zshrc file to setup antigen**

```
source /antigen/antigen.zsh

# Syntax highlighting bundle.
antigen bundle zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting

# Load the theme.
antigen theme robbyrussell

# Tell antigen that you're done.
antigen apply
```

This is my install.conf.yaml for the DotBot configuration

```
- defaults:
    link:
      relink: true

- clean: ['~']

- link:
    ~/.dotfiles: ''
    ~/.zshrc: zshrc

- shell:
  - [git submodule update --init --recursive, Installing submodules]
```

I get a error when I run ./install in my .dotfile folder, to initiate DotBot.

```
GDC113:.dotfiles anders.kitson$ ./install
Submodule 'lib/pyyaml' (https://github.com/anishathalye/pyyaml) registered for path 'lib/pyyaml'
Cloning into 'lib/pyyaml'...
remote: Counting objects: 1761, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (818/818), done.
remote: Total 1761 (delta 618), reused 1761 (delta 618), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1761/1761), 1.31 MiB | 1.07 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (618/618), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'dotbot/lib/pyyaml': checked out 'f30c956c11aa6b5e7827fe5840cc9ed40b938d17'
All targets have been cleaned
~/.dotfiles already exists but is a regular file or directory
Nonexistent target for ~/.zshrc : /Users/anders.kitson/.dotfiles/zshrc
Some links were not successfully set up
Installing submodules [git submodule update --init --recursive]
All commands have been executed

==> Some tasks were not executed successfully
```

My Goal is to setup zsh with anitgen & dotbot as submodues in a git repository that I can track. dotbot should create symlkinks so I can modify my Dot Files and keep them in sync with github and install them on a new machine easily.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: `git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)` @VonC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
Nonexistent target for ~/.zshrc : /Users/anders.kitson/.dotfiles/zshrc
```

In your folder you have this file: **zshrc[h]**

```
# the file ends with extra [h]
zshrch
```

While in the link you have:

```
- link:
    ~/.dotfiles: ''
    ~/.zshrc: zshrc
```

fix any one of them and it will work, since you are referring to an unexisting file.